# Is there a built-in discord feature that allows for 'tagging' of a category channel?

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, discord.js

So basically I have a command in my discord bot that allows the user to set the Category Channel for created text channels. Before I go down another route using arg splitting for " " or another path (which I know how to do, so that would not be an answer to this question,) I would like to know if there is a way that a user could 'tag' the Category Channel if the name is multiple words. (i.e. category name: Help Channels, tagged as: Help-Channels)

The code I am currently using works fine if the category channel is one word, as it is able to properly find the channel within the discord.

```js
let Found = message.guild.channels.find(channel => channel.name === args[1])
```

But I would like to know if there is a way for it to detect the category channel that has multiple words for a name using one argument, before I endeavor on a route that would be less user-friendly to the guild.

Comment: You could use `args.join(' ')` if you do not have any other args.

Comment: @PLASMAchicken there are multiple args :c its all good tho, I have everything working, just was curious if there was a more user-friendly discord feature I could have been utilizing.

Answer (score 1):

As of right now, proper category mentions have yet to be seen within Discord. `<#idOfCategory>` translates, but it isn't a functional channel mention.

That being said, you have a few options.

- Ask for the category ID instead of its name.
- If your command doesn't require any arguments after the category name, splice the array of arguments and join the result.
- Only require the user to have the first word of the category, then check which category name starts with the given string.
- Have your bot list the categories with numbers and choose the one they want and find the category with the given position.
- Use some kind of function to read the next arguments, adding them to a string if combining them with the previous arguments is the start of a category's name like shown below.

```js
let name = '';
let categories = message.guild.channels.filter(c => c.type === 'category');

for (i = 1; i < args.length; i++) {
  let matches = categories.filter(c => c.name.startsWith(name + args[i]));
  if (matches.length > 0) name += `${args[i]} `;
  else break;
}

// 'name' is now the name of the category
```

Comment: I appreciate the ideas, what you said is what I currently have in place, I was just curious if there was a more user-friendly way.